# Creating vector of boost dynamic_bitset in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I want to create an array of dynamic_bitsets. So I created a vector of dynamic_bitset using,

`vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<>> v;`

How can I specify the size of each of these dynamic_bitsets i.e. v[0], v[1] etc? Like in a general case, we specify the size through the constructor.

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(3);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line

```
vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<>> v;
```

create an empty vector. Instead you could have requested it be filled with default entries which all have the same value, so like one usually does

```
vector<int> v(N, 1);
```

to create a vector with `N` entries all 1 you could do

```
vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<>> v( N, boost::dynamic_bitset<>(3) ) ;
```

to have it contain `N` `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`s with 3 bits.

If your vector contains enough elements you should be able to set the `v[i]` to a different size

```
v[i] = boost::dynamic_bitset<>( 100 ) ;
```

Alternative you could create an empty vector like you currently do and just use something like `v.push_back(boost::dynamic_bitset<>(42))` to add correctly sized elements.

Comment: thanks a lot. now i got a clear understanding of how I should access the elements. thanks for providing examples for doing it through several ways. :)