# defining (one/two) dimensional array of boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

Is there a way to have an array of dynamic_bitset in boost? I would like to be able to have both 1-D and 2-D arrays -- Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that would probably be better and yes you can do both, here is an example (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c9fb9c8338d71a)*):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<> > v(10, boost::dynamic_bitset<>(3));

    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl ;

    v[0][2] = 1 ;

    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl ;

    std::vector< std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<> > > vv(3, std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<> >( 3, boost::dynamic_bitset<>(3)) );

    std::cout << vv[0][0] << std::endl ;

    vv[0][0][1] = 1 ;

    std::cout << vv[0][0] << std::endl ;
}
```

This previous thread is a good read too, [Creating vector of boost dynamic_bitset in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133950/creating-vector-of-boost-dynamic-bitset-in-c).

Comment: Using vectors wasn't exactly what I was looking for. But I think it's the best option that I know of. Thank you for the time you took to explain this.